# Define $\sim$ on $\Bbb R^2$ by $(x,y)\sim(z,w)$ iff $|x−y|=|z−w|.$ Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

So I know we have to prove that the relation is transitive, reflexive, and symmetric.

Reflexive: I have to prove that every element of the set is related to itself. By the definition of this relation, wouldn't $|x-y|$ have to equal $|x-y|$ and $|z-w| = |z-w|$? In this case, is it not a given that the relation is reflexive because this will be true for all $x,y$ and $z,w$?

Transitive: If $|x-y| = |z-w|$ and $|z-w| = |d-e|$, then $|x-y| = |d-e|.$ I'm unsure of where to go from here.

Symmetric: $|x-y| = |z-w| \implies |z-w| = |x-y|$. Again isn't this just a given because the order doesn't matter here?

Hopefully my logic isn't too far off. Any further guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reflexivity, all you have to show is $(x,y)\sim(x,y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.  This is that $\lvert x-y\rvert=\lvert x-y\rvert$, which is evidently true.

For transitivity, all you need to follow up on is that $\lvert x-y\rvert = \lvert d-e\rvert$ implies $(x,y)\sim (d,e)$.

For symmetry, again, you just need to follow up and say that $\lvert z-w\rvert=\lvert x-y\rvert$ implies $(z,w)\sim(x,y)$.

This problem is pretty much an exercise to make sure you say everything you need to say to make everything as clear as possible.  As you've noticed, there are no "non-trivial" steps, by which I mean everything is direct application of definition expansion.

---

Broader context (and why I'm answering this question in the first place): consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$.  Recall that equality is an equivalence relation, in particular equality for $\mathbb{R}$ is an equivalence relation.  There is a concept of "pulling back" an equivalence relation through a function.  Define $(x,y)\sim (z,w)$ if and only if $f(x,y)=f(z,w)$.  Since $=$ is an equivalence relation for $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation for $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.  Of course, that's an (easy) theorem you'd have to prove, but it shows that there's nothing special about $\lvert x-y\rvert$ itself.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: A\to B$ be a map. Define $a_1\sim a_2\iff f(a_1)=f(a_2)$. Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. Apply this to your problem.

Comment: This adds very little, if anything, in the way of an answer. It's quite clear that the OP has used the correct definition of an equivalence relation. The problem is in proving $\sim$ to be one.

Comment: @Shaun Hagen is pointing out a general fact, that if you induce a relation on A using a function to a set B that has its own equivalence relation, then the resulting relation is an equivalence relation.  (Granted, this would probably be a better answer if it were more directed to the level of someone who's likely doing one of their first exercises about equivalence relations.)

Comment: That's a fair point, @KyleMiller.

Answer (score 1):

It is reflexive since, given any $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2,$ we have $\lvert a-b\rvert$ equal to itself, and hence $(a,b)\sim(a,b)$.

For transitivity, note that $\sim$ is given by an "if and only if" statement. This allows us to conclude that $(x,y)\sim(d,e)$.

It is symmetric exactly when $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ implies $(c,d)\sim(a,b)$. Thus, let $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$. Then $\lvert a-b\rvert=\lvert c-d\rvert,$ *i.e.*  $\lvert c-d\rvert=\lvert a-b\rvert,$ from which we can conclude $(c,d)\sim(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Reflexive: |x-y| = |x-y|, which is true, so (x, y)~(x, y)

Transitive: |x-y| = |z-w| and |z-w| = |d-e|, then, |x-y|-|z-w| = 0 = |z-w|-|d-e|. So, |x-y|=|d-e|<=> (x, y)~(d, e)

Symmetric: |x-y| = |z-w| <=> |x-y|-|z-w| = 0 <=> -|z-w| = -|x-y| => |z-w| = |x-y| <=> (z, w)~(x, y)